# Python default dictionary returning None for relevant keys

Tags: python, defaultdict, pox

Below is my dictionary

```
path_map = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:(None,None)))
```

I have printed this dictionay below (I am just pasting path_map for for 3 keys only: 00-00-00-00-00-01 to 00-00-00-00-00-03)

```
for key in path_map:
  print key,path_map[key]

00-00-00-00-00-01 defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f9062a17050>, {00-00-00-00-00-05: (1, None), 00-00-00-00-00-03: (2, 00-00-00-00-00-02), 00-00-00-00-00-02: (1, None), 00-00-00-00-00-01: (0, None), 00-00-00-00-00-04: (2, 00-00-00-00-00-02), '00-00-00-00-00-03': (None, None)})

00-00-00-00-00-02 defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f9062a170c8>, {00-00-00-00-00-04: (1, None), 00-00-00-00-00-02: (0, None), 00-00-00-00-00-03: (1, None), 00-00-00-00-00-01: (1, None), 00-00-00-00-00-05: (1, None)})

00-00-00-00-00-03 defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f9062a17140>, {00-00-00-00-00-03: (0, None), 00-00-00-00-00-05: (2, 00-00-00-00-00-02), 00-00-00-00-00-04: (2, 00-00-00-00-00-02), 00-00-00-00-00-02: (1, None), 00-00-00-00-00-01: (2, 00-00-00-00-00-02)})
```

But when I am passing these inputs (src : 00-00-00-00-00-01, dst:00-00-00-00-00-03), I am not getting any value:

```
print path_map[src][dst][0]
print path_map[src][dst][1]
print src
print dst
```

Output :

```
None
None
00-00-00-00-00-01
00-00-00-00-00-03
```

Can someone explain why is it working this way ??

Please note that I am getting values of src and dst from a mysql table where these have been stored in terms of VARCHAR.

Comment: I think what you get makes sense. If you look into your data, you will notice that when src is '00-00-00-00-00-01', path_map[srs] is equal to: {00-00-00-00-00-05: (1, None), 00-00-00-00-00-03: (2, 00-00-00-00-00-02), 00-00-00-00-00-02: (1, None), 00-00-00-00-00-01: (0, None), 00-00-00-00-00-04: (2, 00-00-00-00-00-02), '00-00-00-00-00-03': (None, None)}, so if dest is '00-00-00-00-00-03', path_map[src][dest] will be exactly the last element which is (None,None) and that's exactly what you are looking for. So print path_map[src][dst][0] will be None and print path_map[src][dst][1] will be None

Comment: It looks like you're mixing up strings and some other data type. Your nested dict has both `'00-00-00-00-00-03'` and `00-00-00-00-00-03` as keys, whatever the heck `00-00-00-00-00-03` is.

Comment: yes..I saw that later. I need to check why that's happening. Anyways, I have another query. I have another dictionary :
adjacency = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:None))

 00-00-00-00-00-01 defaultdict(<function <lambda> at x7f4497744ed8>, {00-00-00-00-00-05: 3, 00-00-00-00-00-02: 2})

Is it fine if I use print adjacency[00-00-00-00-00-01][00-00-00-00-00-02][0] to fetch the value

Let me know if I am using wrong syntax

Answer (score 0):

It works exactly as you defined default value in inner `defaultdict`: `lambda:(None,None)`

So, default value for notexistent `path_map[src][dst]` will be tuple `(None,None)`

You see such output because `(None, None)[0] == None` and `(None,None)[1] == None`.